# call functions from JQuery - better way

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call a JQuery function on window resize and also during the initial load. I just tried this, I am sure there is a better way, Please explain this learner,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(function () {
     var doosomething = function () {
         $('#bottomDiv').css('top', $(window).height() - 105);
       }
       $(window).resize(doosomething);
     });
 });
```

Comment: whats wrong with that? If you dont do it that way then just declare the method and use the name instead of inlining it.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){` and `$(function(){` are the same thing.  You only need one, not both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var do_something = function () {
    $('#bottomDiv').css('top', $(window).height() - 105);
  }
  $(window).resize(do_something);
  do_something();
});
```

Your call to `$(function () {` isn't of any use, as it does exactly the same thing as `$(document).ready(function () {`.

Answer (score 3):

No need to name the function just so you can call it.

You can do it like this:

```
$(function () {
  // -----------v-----------assign the handler
   $(window).resize(function () {
       $('#bottomDiv').css('top', $(window).height() - 105);
   }).resize();
});
  // ---^--- invoke the handler
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find window.resize to be unreliable at times. Different browsers call that at different times. (For instance, do you want it to happen "live" or after they stop resizing?)

I would suggest using:
`setInterval(doosomething, 500);`

Or something like that. Your code is fine though, outside of your unnecessary nesting. And not doing an initial call before the resize (if that is what you want to do).